# How to raise forms validation error when ever the user try's to create an object with the object twice

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'v used the unique together model meta, it works but it just comes up with this error. i want to raise a forms validation error, rather than a IntegrityError.

IntegrityError at /name/

UNIQUE constraint failed: canvas_canvas.user_id, canvas_canvas.canvas_name

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/name/
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:

UNIQUE constraint failed: canvas_canvas.user_id, canvas_canvas.canvas_name

Exception Location:     C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 337

```
class Canvas(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    canvas_name         = models.CharField(
                        max_length=100,
                        validators=[
                            # validate_canvas_title,
                            RegexValidator(
                                    regex=CANVAS_REGEX,
                                    message='Canvas must only contain Alpahnumeric characters',
                                    code='invalid_canvas_title'
                                )],
                        )
    slug                = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    background_image    = models.ImageField(
                        upload_to=upload_location,
                        null=True,
                        blank=True,
                        )
# sort catergory into alphabetical order
    category            = models.ForeignKey('category.Category', default=1, blank=True)
    followers           = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='canvas_followed_by', blank=True)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ['user', 'canvas_name']
```

form

```
class CanvasModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Canvas
        fields = ['canvas_name', 'category', 'background_image']
        widgets = {
            'canvas_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'category': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
        }
```

view

```
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

    form_create = CanvasModelCreateForm(request.POST or None)
    if form_create.is_valid():
        instance = form_create.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return redirect('canvases:canvas', username=request.user.username, slug=instance.slug)

    template = 'pages/profile.html'
    context = {
        'user': user,
        'form_create': form_create,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: No. Your form does the validation. But you haven't shown any code, so we can't see what's wrong.

Comment: i'v just updated the question. i think the class meta (unique_together = ['user', 'canvas_name']). is the cause of the error.

Comment: And what is the *actual* error and traceback? And where is the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by passing  `request.user` into the form and use it for validating the `canvas_name`.

You need to override the form's `__init__` method to take an extra keyword argument, `user`. This stores the user in the form, where it's required, and from where you can access it in your clean method.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(CanvasModelCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_canvas_name(self):
    canvas_name = self.cleaned_data.get('canvas_name')
    if Canvas.objects.get(user=self.user, canvas_name=canvas_name).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'Canvas with same name already exists.')
    return canvas_name
```

And you should change in your view like this so,

```
form_create = CanvasModelCreateForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
```